# Button to download a file useing .click(), faulty in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, firefox

The following is contained in a function that compiles a 'url' for a get request and downloads a file when a button is clicked (with an angular ng-click="function" tag).

```
angular.element(link)
   .attr('href', url);

link.click();
```

It works as desired in chrome, but in both IE(9 & 10) and Firefox it simply does nothing. The 'link' object is given the correct 'href' property. I can only think that the .click method is not doing what it is supposed to in IE and Firefox. Any advice?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't use ng-href?

Comment: I have a function that needs to be called with some logic that compiles the url first. I was trying something with " .attr('download', 'transactions.xlsx') " in addition to the href property to change the name of the file that is downloaded. I have gotten it to work with  $window.open(url); but this does nothing for the name of the file.